# set proxy username and password in firefox

Tags: firefox

I am able to set the proxy host and port using the preferences menu, but I see no option to set the username/password.
When I browse, I get a message, proxy is refusing connections. I am using squid proxy.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13):

I had the exact same problem as you had.
And finaly there is no way to add user and password to the default firefox proxy settings, so we need an addon to handle this for us.
In the current version FoxyProxy is doing this without any problems:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/
So try out the Add-On and you will solve this.

br
Wikrie

Comment: THIS. Your answer really helped a LOT! If you developed the addon this is really a crazy good way to promo it too :)

Comment: Such a nifty add-on, I hated entering username and password every time I reopened firefox. You deserve a thumbs up!

Comment: @WiKrle Does it properly encrypt Proxy-Authorization headers when connecting to a HTTPS proxy?

Comment: Confirmed, this is a working solution in 2023.

Answer (score 5):

Open Firefox.

1. In the address bar, type about:config. A warning appears.
2. Click I'll be careful. I promise! A variety of configuration options appears.
3. In the Filter box, type network.negotiate.
4. Double-click network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies to toggle between true and false. The option must be set to false. (It seems counterintuitive, but you set it to false to make it work with the ISA proxy.)

Find the link for detailed understanding https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10522.aspx

Answer (score -5):

Perhaps you must fill the proxy host value with something like the below

username:password@proxy.thing.com

Comment: Firefox ignores the user credentials